# _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'ValueError'>: it's not the same object as builtins.ValueError

Tags: python, pickle

[image]

Input the dataset collected by oneself into Colmap to obtain processed images, camera parameters, and their resolutions are the same. However, when inputting CER-MVSnet, an error occurs. The specific error situation is shown in the figure. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add the image content as pure text (or at least make the image inline in the question).